# How to plot the latent variabel for model estimated by polr?

Tags: r, plot

I want to hear if it's possible to do a plot similar to this one in R (i.e. RStudio):
[image: Latent variable of an ordered model]

The model I'm estimating is:

```
library(MASS)

# with logit
mod1 <- polr(lifesatisfaction) ~ gender + age + income + education + health + work less + work much), data = surveywave5, method = "logistic", Hess = TRUE) 

# with probit
mod1 <- polr(lifesatisfaction) ~ gender + age + income + education + health + work less + work much), data = surveywave5, method = "probit", Hess = TRUE) 


# my data:

 $ lifesatisfaction  : Ord.factor w/ 11 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 9 9 10 10 10 9 11 10 11 7 ...        
 $ gender            : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ income            : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: NA 2 4 5 5 10 7 7 6 3 ...
 $ age               : int  44 40 36 25 39 80 48 32 74 30 ...
 $ education         : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 2 3 7 1 7 3 3 3 5 ...
 $ health            : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 4 1 3 4 5 5 4 4 3 ...
 $ work less         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 NA 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ work much         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 NA 1 2 2 1 2 ...
```

Edit*
I found this way.. however it seems to be similar to str().. but don't know if you can use it as reproducible :/

```
dput(head(surveywave5))
structure(list(gender = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), maritalstatus = c(4, 6, NA, NA, 6, 6), age = c(62, 30, 44, 34, 58, 26), education = c(2, 7, 7, 7, 6, 4), lifesatisfaction = c(7, 8, 10, 7, 7, 8), health = c(4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5), work.much = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), work.less = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), income = c(6, 1, 10, 6, 4, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**###EDIT###**
each curve represent each x-variable used in the model, like this
[image: latent]

So, one curve for age, one curve for gender, health, incme etc.

**###EDIT 2###**
[image: another example]
[image: example of plot]

it seems like you did the plot only for the market variable in your example. i.e. in your example of  `mod2 <- MASS::polr(jobspriv ~ market + agegrp + gender, data=ces)` you used only "market" as the x-axis. I found new picture and draw on it example based on your example of mod2. In your mod2 there are 3 independent variable called market, agegrp and gender, so you sohuld have one curve for each variable. So, each curve should represent each x-var in the model.. meaning that if I have independent 9 variables in my model then there should be 9 curves.

[link to explanation where I got the graph from](https://statmath.wu.ac.at/research/talks/resources/slidesagresti_ordinal.pdf)

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  What have you tried?  Also, you are more likely to get help with a reproducible example.  The snippet of data you included is actually not the data, but a display of the structure of the data.  You can use `dput(surveywave5)` to produce data in a way that can be pasted into your question.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Thanks for your comment! I will like to do a reproducible example but I actually don't know how to do it.. I thought that str() was enough. Using dput() is in my case not a good option since I have over 1200 observation.. I tried dput and the output that coming out is too long to share here. Do you have any example how I can give you a reproducible example? :/

Comment: @DaveArmstrong I tried to do another thing using dput().. don't know if you can use it as reproducible example. I understand that you don't want to give the answer without seeing what I tried but I really don't know how to do it.. I could not find any similar example. If you can mention a package/library and a function then I can try by myself.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer is below, but in order to make it easier, I made a function that would do all of this for you.  First, here's the function.  The front matter of the function (everything with `#'` in the front constitutes the documentation.  The `@param` tags give the parameters and their intended us.  Just copy and paste this chunk into R.  I'll talk about how to use the function below.

```r
#' Plot distributions for ordered logit models
#' 
#' This function plots the distributions for ordered logistic regression models
#' showing the probabilities in each category under each distribution. 
#' @param obj An object of class `polr` estimated from `MASS::polr()`. 
#' @param xvar A string giving the name of the variable to plot on the x-axis. This should not be a factor. 
#' @param xvals Values on the x-axis at which to plot distributions.  This will be most useful with only a few, well-
#' separated values. 
#' @param colors Vector of colors to mark the different categories under the distribution.  This vector should have 
#' as many values as there are levels in the y-variable in the model.
#' @param ylim Limits of the y-axis.  If `NULL` the function will try to find an acceptable value. 
#' @param xlim Limits of the x-axis.  If `NULL` the function tries to find an acceptable value.  
#' @param maxdens Scalar giving the maximum value of the rescaled density to plot.  Defaults to 1. 
#' @param ... Other arguments, currently not implemented. 
plot_ologit_dist <- function(obj, data, xvar, xvals, othervals = NULL, colors=NULL, ylim=c(-12,12), xlim=NULL, maxdens=1, ...){
  dlogis_rescale <- function(s, mu, maxdens = 1){
    md <- dlogis(mu, mu)
    d <- dlogis(s, mu)*(maxdens/md)
    d
  }
  central <- function(x){
    if(is.factor(x)){
      tab <- table(x)
      m <- which.max(tab)
      cent <- factor(m, levels=1:length(levels(x)), labels=levels(x))
    }
    if(!is.factor(x) & length(unique(na.omit(x))) <= 10){
      tab <- table(x)
      cent <- as.numeric(names(tab)[which.max(tab)])
    }
    if(!is.factor(x) & length(unique(na.omit(x))) > 10){
      cent <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)
    }
    return(cent)
  }
  if(is.null(colors)){
    colors <- palette()[1:length(obj$lev)]
  }
  vars <- get_all_vars(formula(obj), data)
  cents <- lapply(vars, central)
  cents[[xvar]] <- xvals
  fake <- do.call(data.frame, cents)
  fxb <- model.matrix(formula(obj), data=fake)[,-1] %*% coef(obj)
  slope <- (fxb[2]-fxb[1])/(xvals[2]-xvals[1])
  intercept <- fxb[1] - xvals[1]*slope
  if(is.null(xlim)){
    xlim <- c(xvals[1], xvals[length(xvals)] + diff(range(xvals))*.2)
  }
  
  if(is.null(xlim)){
    xlim <- range(fxb) + c(-3.6, 3.6)
  }
  z <- obj$zeta
  z <- c(ylim[1], z, ylim[2])
  s <- lapply(1:(length(z)-1), function(i)seq(z[i], z[(i+1)], length=50))
  oldpar <- par()
  outs <- c("cin", "cra", "csi", "cxy", "din", "page")  
  oldpar <- oldpar[setdiff(names(oldpar), outs)]
  lpi <- par()$mar[2]/par()$mai[2]
  levlen <- max(strwidth(obj$lev, units="inches"))
  par(mar = c(3,ceiling(lpi*levlen)+1,1,3))
  plot(xlim, ylim, type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab = "")
  for(j in 1:length(fxb)){
    d <- lapply(seq_along(s), \(i)dlogis_rescale(s[[i]], fxb[j], maxdens = maxdens))
    lapply(seq_along(d), \(i)lines(d[[i]] + xvals[j], s[[i]]))
    lapply(seq_along(d), \(i){
      polygon(x=c(d[[i]] + xvals[j], rep(xvals[j], length(d[[i]])), d[[i]][1]+ xvals[j]), 
              y=c(s[[i]], rev(s[[i]]), s[[i]][1]), 
              lty = 0, 
              col = colors[i])
    })
  }
  ylv <- z[1:(length(z)-1)] + (z[2:length(z)] - z[1:(length(z)-1)])/2
  
  axis(1)
  abline(h = obj$zeta, lty=3)
  axis(2, at=ylv, labels=obj$lev, las=1)
  mtext("Latent Propensity", 4, line=1)
  mtext(xvar, 1, line=2)
  box()  
  suppressWarnings(do.call(par, oldpar))
  
}
```

I've got a couple of different examples.  The first one uses data that I just made up that has 3 values for y. The code below makes the data and estimates the model.

```r
x <- rnorm(250)
z <- sample(0:1, 250, replace=TRUE)
b <- c(2, .75)

xb <- cbind(x,z) %*% b

tau <- c(-Inf, -3, 1, Inf)

q <- sapply(tau, \(t)plogis(t-xb))
p <- q[,2:4]-q[,1:3]
y <- apply(p, 1, \(x)which.max(rmultinom(1, 1, x)))

dat <- data.frame(x=x, z=z, y=as.factor(y))
mod <- MASS::polr(y ~ x + z, data=dat)
```

Now, you can use the function to make the plot.  The `xvar` argument wants the name of the variable to plot on the x-axis (as a string).  The `xvals` argument takes the values on the x-axis at which distributions will be plotted.

```r
plot_ologit_dist(mod, dat, xvar="x", xvals=c(-3, -1, 1, 3))
```

[image]

The next example comes from some data in the `psre` package, which you will have to install if you don't have it already. In this example, I had to play around a bit with `maxdens` and `xlim` to get the plot to look just right.

```r
data("ces", package="psre")
mod2 <- MASS::polr(jobspriv ~ market + agegrp + gender, data=ces)
plot_ologit_dist(mod2, 
                 ces, 
                 xvar="market", 
                 xvals=c(-1,0,1), 
                 maxdens=.75, 
                 xlim=c(-1,1.75))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Hopefully this makes it possible for you to make the plots.

---

##### Original Answer:

Here's an example.  First, we can make some data and run the model

```r
x <- rnorm(250)
z <- sample(0:1, 250, replace=TRUE)
b <- c(2, .75)

xb <- cbind(x,z) %*% b

tau <- c(-Inf, -3, 1, Inf)

q <- sapply(tau, \(t)plogis(t-xb))
p <- q[,2:4]-q[,1:3]
y <- apply(p, 1, \(x)which.max(rmultinom(1, 1, x)))

dat <- data.frame(x=x, z=z, y=as.factor(y))
mod <- MASS::polr(y ~ x + z, data=dat)
```

Next, we are going to make two datasets - one that will draw the line (`fake2`) and one that will have the points for which we'll draw distributions (`fake`). In these datasets, you need all of the variables in the model.  Every one by the one you're plotting on `x` should be constant (presumably at some central value).

```r
fake <- data.frame(y = factor(1, levels=1:3), z=0, x=seq(-3,3,length=4))
fake2 <- data.frame(y = factor(1, levels=1:3), z=0, x=seq(-3,4.1,length=4))
```

Next, we can make the the linear predictor using both fake datasets:

```r
fxb <- model.matrix(formula(mod), data=fake)[,-1] %*% coef(mod)
fxb2 <- model.matrix(formula(mod), data=fake2)[,-1] %*% coef(mod)
```

Now, we have to make the y-values at which we'll plot the distributions.  This was a bit of trial and error initially - trying to get the right lower and upper bounds.  I made this so there are 25 values between the minimum value and the first threshold (`mod$zeta[1]`), 25 values between the thresholds: `mod$zeta[1]` and `mod$zeta[2]` and finally 25 values from the upper threshold to the maximum.

```r
s <- c(seq(-12, mod$zeta[1], length=25), 
       seq(mod$zeta[1], mod$zeta[2], length=25), 
       seq(mod$zeta[2], 12, length=25))
```

Then, we can start making the plot.  First, we plot the line:

```r
par(mar = c(3,5.5,1,3))
plot(fake2$x, fxb2, type="l", ylim=c(-12, 12), xlim=c(-3,4.1), 
     axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab = "")
```

Next, we need to know the density to plot for the distribution.  We can get this from the logistic distribution PDF (`dlogis()`) which is centred at the value of the linear predictor. Since these are density values, they need to be scaled up so the distribution will be visible. Here are the density values for the first distribution:

```r
d1 <- dlogis(s, fxb[1])*5 + -3
```

Now, we can draw in the density line.  Note here that the density values are on `x` and the `s` values are on `y`:

```r
lines(d1, s)
```

Next, we need to fill in the pieces of the distribution.  We use the `polygon()` function to do this.  To do this, we need to specify a set of fully connected x-y pairs.  I'm using the `d1` values for `x` and the `s` values for `y`:

```r
polygon(c(d1[1:25], rep(fake$x[1], 25), d1[1]), 
        y=c(s[1:25], s[25:1], s[1]), 
        col=rgb(1,0,0,.25), lty=0)
```

Next, we do the same with the other two pieces of the distribution:

```r
polygon(c(d1[26:50], rep(fake$x[1], 25), d1[26]), 
        y=c(s[26:50], s[50:26], s[26]), 
        col=rgb(0,1,0,.25), lty=0)
polygon(c(d1[51:75], rep(fake$x[1], 25), d1[51]), 
        y=c(s[51:75], s[75:51], s[51]), 
        col=rgb(0,0,1,.25), lty=0)
```

Then, we just repeat this for the other values of `x` for which we want to plot distributions:

```r
d2 <- dlogis(s, fxb[2])*5 + -1
lines(d2, s)
polygon(c(d2[1:25], rep(fake$x[2], 25), d2[1]), 
        y=c(s[1:25], s[25:1], s[1]), 
        col=rgb(1,0,0,.25), lty=0)
polygon(c(d2[26:50], rep(fake$x[2], 25), d2[26]), 
        y=c(s[26:50], s[50:26], s[26]), 
        col=rgb(0,1,0,.25), lty=0)
polygon(c(d2[51:75], rep(fake$x[2], 25), d2[51]), 
        y=c(s[51:75], s[75:51], s[51]), 
        col=rgb(0,0,1,.25), lty=0)

d3 <- dlogis(s, fxb[3])*5 + 1
lines(d3, s)
polygon(c(d3[1:25], rep(fake$x[3], 25), d3[1]), 
        y=c(s[1:25], s[25:1], s[1]), 
        col=rgb(1,0,0,.25), lty=0)
polygon(c(d3[26:50], rep(fake$x[3], 25), d3[26]), 
        y=c(s[26:50], s[50:26], s[26]), 
        col=rgb(0,1,0,.25), lty=0)
polygon(c(d3[51:75], rep(fake$x[3], 25), d3[51]), 
        y=c(s[51:75], s[75:51], s[51]), 
        col=rgb(0,0,1,.25), lty=0)

d4 <- dlogis(s, fxb[4])*5 + 3
lines(d4, s)
polygon(c(d4[1:25], rep(fake$x[4], 25), d4[1]), 
        y=c(s[1:25], s[25:1], s[1]), 
        col=rgb(1,0,0,.25), lty=0)
polygon(c(d4[26:50], rep(fake$x[4], 25), d4[26]), 
        y=c(s[26:50], s[50:26], s[26]), 
        col=rgb(0,1,0,.25), lty=0)
polygon(c(d4[51:75], rep(fake$x[4], 25), d4[51]), 
        y=c(s[51:75], s[75:51], s[51]), 
        col=rgb(0,0,1,.25), lty=0)
abline(h=mod$zeta, lty=2)
axis(1)
axis(2, at=c(-7.5, -.9, 6.55), labels=c("Outcome 1", "Outcome 2", "Outcome 3"), las=1)
mtext("Latent Propensity", 4, line=1)
mtext("Values of X", 1, line=2)
box()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I suspect there is a considerably more elegant way of doing this, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer! There are for now 3 things I'm in doubt about and don't understand. 1) why two data frames are needed? 2) what should I use as the two data frames? and 3) In 'fake' why do you have x=seq(-3, 3,length=4) and in fake2 why x=seq(-3,4.1,length=4)?

Comment: honestly I used several days to understand your codes but I really didn't understooth so much.. what and where I should replace my own dataframe, dependent variable (y variable) and independent variables (x variables). Can you help with this?

Comment: @rr19 I added a new piece to the answer where I make a function that will make the plot for you.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and that you actually want to take time to do it! I'm not sure that I from the begingin explained what I exactly want. The reason that I'm in doubt of what you did in your new example... I updated my post with header EDIT 2 with an explanation

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure what you're hoping to get with different variables along the x-axis.  For example, you would have a single distribution for gender, but for that to work, you would need to choose a single value for gender and the same for the other variables.  Further, I don't know how you would draw the line going through them as there would not naturally exist such a line in the model.